# Spring <mvc:resources>: How to make it server an index-file/welcome-file if a directory is queried?

Tags: spring-mvc

Most webservers can be configured to deliver a special file if just a directory is queried. Typically the file "index.html" or similar is delivered in this case.

I am using `<mvc:resources>` to deliver static resources in a spring application and I want to do the same: If a directory is queried a pre-specified file within that directory should be delivered to the client. My configuration so far looks like this:

```java
public class CoreWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/static/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("/www/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To my suprise I did not find anything bundled with spring that solves that problem. After all it seems rather normal.

## Possible solution

One way I have found is to write a custom path resolver like this:

```java
public class CoreWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/static/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("/www/")
            .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new WelcomeFilePathResolver());
    }

    /**
     * An extension to Spring's {@link PathResourceResolver} which checks if the requested resource is a directory.
     * If it is, it attempts to deliver a file "index.html" within this directory rather than failing.
     */
    private static class WelcomeFilePathResolver extends PathResourceResolver {
        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(final String resourcePath, final Resource location) throws IOException {
            Resource resource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
            if (resource.getFile().isDirectory()) {
                return super.getResource(resourcePath + "/index.html", location);
            }
            return super.getResource(resourcePath, location);
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that this does not work for the root directory, but only for subdirectories. For the root directory add the following to your extension of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```

## Background explanation

Usually if you do not register a `resourceChain`, then spring will resolve the resources using a `PathResourceResolver`. The original method `PathResourceResolver.getResource` starts like this:

```java
protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
    Resource resource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
    if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
```

There the directory is found, `resource.exists()` returns true, but `resource.isReadable()` returns false because a directory itself is not readable and thus this will end up in a 404.

The customized `ResourceResolver` intercepts calls to this method and checks whether the requested resource is a directory. If it not it just delegates to the original `getResource`-method. However if it is, it changes the path and looks for an index.html file within that directory.

The reason the extra configuration for root is needed is because [the ResourceHttpRequestHandler checks for non empty paths](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/436486b8a1cab5a37a415c7560ee6dea8014bf9b/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java#L403) (not sure why it is dictating that and not leaving this up to the ResourceResolve...).

## Limitations

Since I call `resource.getFile()` I suppose that there a number of cases where this won't work. I testet it wil files delivered from a war-file in Tomcat. However if resources are read directly from a jar file this will probably not work. An adaption where not `.getFile().isDirectory()` but rather `resource.isReadable()` is checked could be used as an alternative.